# What IP addresses to use in public bug reports if the actual ones are confidential?

Tags: documentation, privacy

I am wondering what is best practice for using IP addresses in publicly available reports, e.g. bug reports, if I don't want to use the actual one for privacy reasons and don't want to confuse people who actually want to help me.

I considered addresses from the TEST-NETs, see [RFC 5737](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5737):

> ```
>   192.0.2.0/24     -   TEST-NET-1
>   198.51.100.0/24  -   TEST-NET-2
>   203.0.113.0/24   -   TEST-NET-3
> ```

But it is not clear for me what this paragraph means:

RFC 5737, section 4:

> Addresses within the TEST-NET-1, TEST-NET-2, and TEST-NET-3 blocks
> SHOULD NOT appear on the public Internet and are used without any
> coordination with IANA or an Internet registry [RFC2050].

Does that mean, one should use it only for in-house documentation or no device should appear on the Internet claiming has one address from the test nets?

The other option is to use private IP addresses, e.g. from 10.0.0.0/8.

Anything else?

What is considered best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does that mean, one should use it only for in-house documentation or no device should appear on the Internet claiming has one address from the test nets?

The latter -- no device on the Internet should use one of those IP addresses.  Documentation published to the Internet could and should use them.

I was confused at first, because I thought you were talking about [RFC 1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918).  It specifies the private IP address ranges that I am very familiar with:

> ```
>  10.0.0.0        -   10.255.255.255  (10/8 prefix)
>  172.16.0.0      -   172.31.255.255  (172.16/12 prefix)
>  192.168.0.0     -   192.168.255.255 (192.168/16 prefix)
> ```

But [RFC 5737](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5737) is different, using IP address ranges I have never heard of.

> The blocks 192.0.2.0/24 (TEST-NET-1), 198.51.100.0/24 (TEST-NET-2),
> and 203.0.113.0/24 (TEST-NET-3) are provided for use in
> documentation.

The purpose of setting aside these IP networks for use in documentation, is to ensure that documentation (such as [documentation showing how to use NAT software](http://www.fwbuilder.org/4.0/docs/users_guide/nat-cookbook.html)) will never use any IP address that could ever be in use anywhere.  That is, not on the Internet and not on any private networks.  This way, if someone accidentally ran one of those example commands by doing a copy/paste from that documentation page, it would have no effect on any real networks.

Comment: And to give an answer: One can use both, **private** addresses or **test-net** addresses. While it's more common to use **private** addresses, simply because RFC 5737 is less known, there are scenarios, where test-net addresses are needed, like the NAT scenario described above.

Answer (score 2):

The IETF documentation uses the 192.0.2.0/24 prefixes for example documentation, so I'd suggest you use something from that.

It is documented in [RFC5735](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5735.txt) as the "test net", which specifically says:

```
192.0.2.0/24 - This block is assigned as "TEST-NET" for use in
documentation and example code.  It is often used in conjunction with
domain names example.com or example.net in vendor and protocol
documentation.  Addresses within this block should not appear on the
public Internet.
```

Comment: Ah, sorry. I miss understood you. I thought you have an actual *use* of the 192.0.2.0/24 addresses in documentation and did not meant to link to the documentation of "how to use".

Comment: http://www.fwbuilder.org/4.0/docs/users_guide/nat-cookbook.html  Here is a document that uses it while giving example commands.

Comment: @Kevin Panko: Thanks! That's IMHO a good example. Describing a NAT setting, it actually makes use of both **private** addresses and **non-private** addresses from **TEST-NET**. Here one can clearly understand the need for non-private example addresses. If you agree, please integrate this aspect in your answer and I will accept it. Thanks again for helping organizing my mind.